# virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable..!

Tags: python, cmd, flask, virtualenv

I'm beginner of Flask development.

While I tried to use virtualenv, it keeps show me the errors.
I search through the web and tried everything they recommended, such as upgrading virtualenv, moving DLLs folder, moving Python35.dll file, etc. But it doesn't work!

I also have problem with activating, 
C:\Users\형철\venv\activate 
It also doesn't work...

Please give me a help..for these 2 problems.

My python version is 3.5
And I use window 8.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\형철>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\형철\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35'
New python executable in venv\Scripts\python.exe
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\형철\venv\lib\site.py", line 703, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\형철\venv\lib\site.py", line 670, in main
virtual_install_main_packages()
File "C:\Users\형철\venv\lib\site.py", line 554, in virtual_install_main_packa
ges
sys.real_prefix = f.read().strip()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 9: illegal
multibyte sequence
ERROR: The executable venv\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is 'c:\\users\\형철' (should be 'c:\\users\\형철\\ve
nv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
Note: some Windows users have reported this error when they installed Python for
"Only this user" or have multiple versions of Python installed. Copying the app
ropriate PythonXX.dll to the virtualenv Scripts/ directory may fix this problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are other env settings that resolve this, but I would override the `WORKON_HOME` variable (determines where virtualenvs are stored) to use something that doesn't have the Hangul characters, it seems to struggle with these. I'm able to reproduce:

```
.whogan:~/tmp$ export WORKON_HOME=~/tmp/형철
.whogan:~/tmp$ mkvirtualenv django-dev
New python executable in django-dev/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: The executable django-dev/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/home/whogan/tmp/\ud615\ucca0' (should be u'/home/whogan/tmp/\ud615\ucca0/django-dev')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Switching `WORKON_HOME` to another path resolves this:

```
.whogan:~/tmp$ export WORKON_HOME=~/tmp/venvs
.whogan:~/tmp$ mkvirtualenv django-dev
New python executable in django-dev/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
(django-dev).whogan:~/tmp$
```

Perhaps set to C:\virtualenvs or similar.

If this is not using `virtualenvwrapper`, the `WORKON_HOME` advice is invalid. Instead you can `cd` to another directory first:

```
mkdir c:\virtualenvs
cd C:\virtualenvs
virtualenv (the virtualenv name)
```